# Why is an extra semicolon not allowed after the return statement, when it is allowed for other statements?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return

I put an extra semicolon after the semicolon of `System.out.println`:

```
System.out.println();;
```

Which was legal to Java compiler, so I checked for other statements and they were all legal too. So when I searched and found these links:

1. [Why does Java not show an error for double semicolon at the end of a statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9546455)
2. [Compiler doesn't complain when I ended a line with two semicolons. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7571007)
3. [When would you put a semicolon after a method closing brace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2724371)
4. [Why does code with successive semi-colons compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10491729)
5. [Semicolon at end of 'if' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14112515)

I came to understand that an extra semicolon means an extra empty statement.

But when I put an extra semicolon after a `return` statement, I got a compile time error. I came to the conclusion that the `return` statement is considered to be the last statement in the flow of execution, so putting an extra statement after the `return` is illegal.

The same thing happens in this code too:

```
if(a == b)
    System.out.println();;
else
    System.out.println();
```

Inside the `if` statement `System.out.println();;` gives a compile time error, because the compiler is expecting `elseif` or `else`. Am I right or is is there some other reason?

Comment: b/c it's an unreachable statement.

Comment: Yes, unreachable statements are not allowed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546455/why-does-java-not-show-an-error-for-double-semicolon-at-the-end-of-a-statement?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why multiple semicolon is not allowed after the return statement, when
>   it is allowed for all other statement?

Simply because when you have a statement like

```
System.out.println();;
```

This means you have two statements, one is `System.out.println();` and other statement is after the first `semi colon`, it is empty and that's allowed **BUT** you can't have any empty statement or any other statement after the `return` statement because **it will never execute**, in other words, **its unreachable statement** and you **can't have unreachable statements** in your code.

> Same thing happens in this code too

```
if(a == b)
    System.out.println();;
else
    System.out.println();
```

that's because, when you have an `else` statement, statement just before it should be `if` statement which is not the case in above code snippet because statement just before `else` statement is an `empty statement` which is not allowed.

If you have parenthesis after the `if statement` like

```
if(a == b) {
    System.out.println();;
}
else
   System.out.println();
```

you will get no errors because now empty statement is inside an `if block` and the statement just before `else` is `if statement` and not the `empty statement` which was the case when you had no parenthesis after `if statement`

Answer (score 4):

Your code:

```
if (a == b)
    System.out.println();;
else
    System.out.println();
```

is equivalent to

```
if (a == b) System.out.println();
;
else System.out.println();
```

And you can't use an `else` if the preceding statement is not an `if`.

Comment: Ya you are right, what I explained in the question was wrong

Answer (score 2):

The Java Language Specification [§14.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) says:

> It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because it is *unreachable*.

An extra semicolon (inside a method) is parsed as a separate "empty statement" ([JLS §14.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6)). If you return from the method, those later statements aren't reachable. Hence the compiler is required to give an error.

Interestingly, the reachability rules have an exception to make it convenient to use an `if` statement for conditional compilation like C's `#if`. So merely putting an always-true `if` statement before the `return` is enough to satisfy the JLS that any following statements are "reachable":

```
if (true) return;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;System.out.print("'reachable', but not really");;;
```

(Those extra semicolons are physically after the `return;`, but semantically, they are after the `if`.)

Other statements which, like `return`, control the program flow, can also cause statements to be unreachable. These extra semicolons are also not allowed:

- `throw null;;;;;;;;;;;` — because the thrown `NullPointerException` exits the block
- `while (true);;;;;;;;;;;;;;` — because the loop never exits
- `while (true) { break;;;;;;;;;;;; }` — because the loop always exits early
- `while (true) { continue;;;;;;;;; }` — because the loop always repeats early
- `while (false) { ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; }` — because the loop never runs at all!

Answer (score 1):

When you use :

```
System.out.println();;
```

A new semicolon makes a new empty statement and it is ok to the compiler.
But when you have

```
return;
```

It is not allowed because you cannot put any more statements after the return statement because when the method returns, it stops there and the statements after it would never get called so it is not allowed!